# search a database where column = array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, database

i am trying to see if you can search a database with an array of strings instead of just one

```
if current_user.role == 'Coach' 
  @groups.each do |group| 
    @groupchats << group.id 
  end 
else 
  @mygroups.each do |group|
    @groupchats << group.group_id 
  end 
end 

@groupchatss = Chat.where("group_id= "+@groupchats.to_s+"").order('created_at DESC')
```

so it searches the database where `group_id= [0,1,2,3]` or whatever the array actually is

i am wondering if this is actually possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use sql operator `IN` to do this. Rails will generate right sql query for you:

```
@groupchatss = Chat.where(group_id: @groupchats).order('created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that a linq contains would work well when searching against an array

Something like: 
`db.mytable.where(p=>p.groupid.contains(myarray);`